# How to send multipart with request in python, but without requests_toolbelt

Tags: python-requests

I have to upload a zip file to an API and I have to provide an ID value.
When I use the curl command below, it works just fine.

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://127.0.0.1:8900/api/' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
  -H 'X-CSRFTOKEN: 'xxxx' \
  -F 'device_id=1' \
  -F 'counters=@counters.zip;type=application/x-zip-compressed'
```

I am trying not to achieve the same with a python script and request. I have read some other topics but they all recommend to use requests_toolbelt which is not available to me on the target system as I can't install any python modules.

```
import requests

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8900/api/' 
headers = {
    'accept': '*/*',
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    'X-CSRFTOKEN': 'xxxx',
}

payload = {
    'device_id': '1'),
}

files = {
    'file': ('counters.zip', open('counters.zip', 'rb'), 'application/x-zip-compressed'),
}
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)
```

When I try like this then I get this error:

"multipart form parse error - Invalid boundary in multipart: None"

I was expecting request to take care about the boundary when I use data and file in the same request. But it seems not the case.